# Better way to set active class in Bootstrap UI elements

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a Bootstrap button group that I use to control filtering:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group" role="group" aria-label="AM/PM">
  <a href="/PrivateHires/StateFair?ampm=am" role="button" class="btn btn-default">AM</a>
  <a href="/PrivateHires/StateFair?ampm=pm" role="button" class="btn btn-default">PM</a>
</div>
```

Adding `active` to `a` element's `class` will make the button appear to be selected.

My current, inelegant approach, is to use a `if` statement:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group" role="group" aria-label="AM/PM">
@if (ViewData["ampm"].ToString() == "AM")
{
    <a href="/FooController/Foo?ampm=am" role="button" class="btn btn-default active">AM</a>
    <a href="/FooController/Foo?ampm=pm" role="button" class="btn btn-default">PM</a>
}
else
{
    <a href = "/FooController/Foo?ampm=am" role="button" class="btn btn-default">AM</a>
    <a href = "/FooController/Foo?ampm=pm" role="button" class="btn btn-default active">PM</a>
}
</div>
```

I created a function, but couldn't get the `a` syntax to work:

```
public string active(string AmPm)
{
    if (ViewData["ampm"].ToString()==AmPm){ return "class='active'"; }
    else { return ""; }
}

...

<a href="/FooController/Foo?ampm=am" role="button" class="btn btn-default @ative('AM')">AM</a>
<a href="/FooController/Foo?ampm=pm" role="button" class="btn btn-default @active('PM')">PM</a>
```

Is there a more-elegant way to set the `active` class?  In general, is there a better way to modify UI elements based on query string values?

Comment: The method approach sounds fines to me. You need to return just  the `active` string as you already have `class=""` in the markup.

Comment: Use `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["ampm"]` instead of `ViewData`. Using `ViewData` is dependent on something actually setting that key in `ViewData`, which is easy to overlook or forget. If it's passed in the query string, it will always be in `RouteData.Values`.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the function:

```
@functions
{
  public string ActiveAmPm(string ampm)
  {
    if (ViewData["ampm"].ToString() == ampm) { return "active"; }
    else { return ""; }
  }
}
```

then referenced it:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group" role="group" aria-label="AM/PM">
    <a href="/FooController/Foo?ampm=am" role="button" class='btn btn-default @ActiveAmPm("AM")'>AM</a>
    <a href="/FooController/Foo?ampm=pm" role="button" class='btn btn-default @ActiveAmPm("PM")'>PM</a>
</div>
```

Comment: don't really need the else... just the `return "";`